# requests exception: max retries exceeded, Errno 60 operation timed out

Tags: python, python-requests, httpconnection

When I was crawling data from a webpage, I got a max retry error. And although I've searched for it online, the Errno code seems to be different from what I had.

> `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host={},port={}): Max retries exceeded with url: {} (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at {}>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'`

I'm crawling websites with different remote host addresses, and only for this one address my script went wrong. In other cases it worked as usual. I tried to add time.sleep() but it didn't help with this error. So I think this error is not because I'm sending too many requests to the server. 
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

The url it is failing on: 
http://222.175.25.10:8403/ajax/npublic/NData.ashx?jsoncallback=jQuery1111054523240929524232_1457362751668&Method=GetMonitorDataList&entCode=37150001595&subType=&subID=&year=2016&itemCode=&dtStart=2015-01-01&dtEnd=2015-12-31&monitoring=1&bReal=false&page=1&rows=500&_=1457362751769

(Because the pages I'm crawling are generated by js so I reconstructed the url myself. )

Update: it is working now! The reason seems to be just that the website timed out.

Comment: Can you post the URL its failing on?

Comment: Hi! @sisnared I edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: That does not work in the browser, are you using this is a session or how exactly?

Comment: It's working now. It was just timing out when you last tried it I guess.

Comment: @sisanared Yes! I think that is the reason. I tried this morning and it's working. Thank you!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm using the get method of requests session.